# Hibernate annotations custom property/column names for HQL query

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-annotations

I started converting from .hbm.xml files to annotations and got the following in my .hbm.xml file

```
    <property name="Phonenumber" column="phonenumber" ... />
```

My problem is that in many Hibernate queries I use the property like this

```
String queryString = "from Contact where Phonenumber like Something order by Somethingelse";
Query query = ContactDAO.getSession().createQuery(queryString);
```

So I always get an error because the property "Phonenumber" couldn't be found, as soon as I change "Phonenumber" to "phonenumber" everything works fine.

I thought about 3 solutions for my problem...

1. search for every occurence of "Phonenumber" and change it to phonenumber (I hopefully don't have to do this because we have
   properties with a few thousand occurrences...)
2. find a way to tell hibernate that it should "map" the column name to a property which starts with an uppercase letter... will
   also be a problem (but much smaller than 1.) because there are
   properties where not only the first letter is different. eg.

   ```
   <property name="defaultPhoneNumber" column="phoneNumber" ... />
   ```
3. find something equal to style in the .hbm.xml where it was possible to define property name and property column

Anyone has an idea how to save the huge amount of time changing all properties to the correct one?

I already took a look at the Hibernate NamingStrategy, but I don't think it's what I need.